# Age based "Select Case"

Tags: vb.net, select-case

So I am trying to code a button that reads the age entered by the user and determines what price they receive. Below is how I have tried doing this with no luck.

```
 Private Sub btnSelect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSelect.Click
    Dim txtage As String
    txtage = lblPrice.Text.ToUpper
    Select Case txtage
        Case CStr(0) To CStr(3)
            lblPrice.Text = "0"
        Case CStr(4) To CStr(63)
            lblPrice.Text = "9"

    End Select

End Sub
```

I have 
     Option Explicit On,
     Option Strict On,
     Option Infer Off,

What am I missing or doing wrong here? Please and thank you.

Comment: It looks like to reading from a label not a textbox???

Comment: since it looks like you are after a range, integers would make more sense than strings.

Comment: im trying to read from a txtAge and display the price lblPrice

Comment: when I switch to integer, option strict catches errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then get the value from the right place, and use some code protection with `Integer.TryParse` since your reading from a string.

```
Private Sub btnSelect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSelect.Click
  Dim age As Integer
  If Integer.TryParse(txtage.Text, age) Then
    Select Case age
      Case 0 To 3
        lblPrice.Text = "0"
      Case 4 To 63
        lblPrice.Text = "9"
    End Select
  End If
End Sub
```